# What is the return type of DateTimePicker in WinForm Application?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, phpmyadmin, datetimepicker

I want to store a date in phpmyadmin. There are various types of fields related to `Date` and `time` in phpmyadmin (e.g) `Timestamp, DateTime, Date etc...`

I am getting date in my form using `DateTimePicker`. I have no idea which kind of data type should I choose in my date and time fields in phpmyadmin when I will be saving that prompted date and time from Datetimepicker in database. Is datetimepicker gets saved in phpmyadmin using Date data type or `DateTime` data type...?

Comment: Next time press F1 in Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

The DateTimePicker.Value has the type of [System.DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> **Remarks**
>
> If the Value property has not been changed in code or by the user, it
>   is set to the current date and time ([DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

It returns a DateTime value

```
DateTime date1 = datetimepicker1.Value;
```